# Redis at some-redis:6379: Name or service not known

Tags: docker, redis

I am running Docker with Hyper-V on Windows 10 Enterprise and attempting to create a Redis container using the official latest Redis image. I followed the instructions on the Docker website (https://www.docker.com/blog/how-to-use-the-redis-docker-official-image/) but I am encountering the following error:

```
Redis at some-redis:6379: Name or service not known
```

I do feel like I'm missing something, but not sure why as this is what the documentations say, but maybe it was just a general idea of how to set it up? Also, there is no `Dockerfile` so maybe that's missing.

Maybe the network commands are wrong:

```
docker network create some-network
​​docker run -it --network some-network --rm redis redis-cli -h some-redis
```

Shouldn't it be a bridged network, and shouldn't there be a `Dockerfile` with these settings in it?

Comment: How did you start the Redis server container?

Comment: (The `docker network create` network probably is a bridged network, you don't have to explicitly specify it.  Options like the network name can't go in a Dockerfile, and since you're only using the prebuilt `redis` image you don't necessarily need one.  For some use cases a Docker Compose setup could be useful, but it's not necessarily clear what application code might be connecting to this Redis store.)

Comment: Thank you! Understood. By the way I start the server using the `docker run` which seem to also start the Redis server because after the error above I see the Redis cli just saying that I'm not connected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The containers you create need to stay in the same Docker network in order to be able to communicate.

In your case, first create the network:

```
docker network create some-network
```

then create the redis-server, with the specification of the network (just created) and port to expose:

```
docker run --name some-redis --network some-network -p 6379:6379 -d redis redis-server --save 60 1 --loglevel warning
```

finally, start the cli on the same network that will bind to the 6379 port:

```
docker run -it --network some-network --rm redis redis-cli -h some-redis
```